# How do I eliminate triplicated rows while retaining duplicated rows (SQL server 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates

I want to be careful to ask the question I want answering rather than try to distill it to one step in the process, so please bear with my "stream of consciousness" style. My distilled question would be as the title suggests **"How do I eliminate triplicated rows while retaining duplicated rows (so without grouping)?"** but I will accept answers that work at any step of the process to get what I want. Using SQL server 2016.

I am trying to find "zero billing calls" in our database. The first definition I used was this code

```
SELECT  

     max([Inbound Call Client Account]) as [account]

      ,convert(date,format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Inbound Call Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) as [Date]

     ,max([Activation Id]) as [Activation Id]

  FROM [Call_Table]

  where 

  convert(date,format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Inbound Call Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) >= '2017-09-01'

  and [Chargeable Duration] = 0

  and ([Inbound Connected Call Duration] IS NULL or [Inbound Connected Call Duration] <1)

  and [Inbound Call Type] = 'normal operator call'

  group by [Inbound Call Time]
```

Basically any answered call (normal operator call) with zero (or minimal) duration figures. I grouped by inbound call time because each call that fits the definition has two rows and I want to do a count in an SSRS report so I only want one row per call.

This has identified the calls I want however it has also brought back calls I don't want.

```
account   Date             Activation Id
310722  06/09/2017  15CD7A85-084D-4276-BC80-B5369710EC28
310722  06/09/2017  AA145DE5-A278-4181-8EEF-0AFC4B38F2A8
310722  06/09/2017  71413B46-CDC8-41A2-AD3D-2CE88B7C851F
...
310722  14/09/2017  F36E147A-AC39-4441-9472-225FFD56E013
310722  14/09/2017  04372920-DDC4-47DC-8D9E-1E807441CDB3
```

I know (from previous work) that the calls on the 14th are genuine 0 billing and the ones on the 6th are not. So I looked into what the difference is.

```
SELECT 
      [Inbound Call Client Account]

      ,[Inbound Call Type]


      ,[Chargeable Duration]
      ,[Activation Id]

      ,[Inbound Call Time]

  FROM [Call_Table]

  where [activation id] = '15CD7A85-084D-4276-BC80-B5369710EC28'

  or [activation id] = 'F36E147A-AC39-4441-9472-225FFD56E013'

  or [activation id] = 'AA145DE5-A278-4181-8EEF-0AFC4B38F2A8'

  or [activation id] = '04372920-DDC4-47DC-8D9E-1E807441CDB3' 

  or [activation id] = '71413B46-CDC8-41A2-AD3D-2CE88B7C851F'
```

which generated

[image: output]

The clear distinguishing feature (to me) is that the false positives have 3 rows of data with the same activation id. Is there a way to incorporate this distinction into my original query so these no longer appear? But the true positives on the 14th have duplicated rows so to my knowledge a group by won't work.

Comment: Apologies. Edited in.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `HAVING` will be the easiest way. But for this you should use `GROUP BY` Does this query help you?

```
SELECT  

     max([Inbound Call Client Account]) as [account]

      ,convert(date,format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Inbound Call Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) as [Date]

     ,max([Activation Id]) as [Activation Id]

  FROM [Call_Table]

  where 

  convert(date,format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Inbound Call Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) >= '2017-09-01'

  and [Chargeable Duration] = 0

  and ([Inbound Connected Call Duration] IS NULL or [Inbound Connected Call Duration] <1)

  and [Inbound Call Type] = 'normal operator call'

  group by [Inbound Call Time],[Activation Id]
  HAVING Count([Activation Id]) < 3
```

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '03C51B68-F1AA-4400-944A-2778A4BA6154' to data type int.

Comment: Soory it Should be
 group by [Inbound Call Time],Count([Activation Id])
 HAVING Count([Activation Id]) < 3

Comment: Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.                               p.s. it is ok to just post error messages? Don't want to come across as rude to someone trying to help

Comment: I think it's not rude, but i am a newbie so i am not sure :) i edit the query can you check again

Comment: The idea is to come up with working solutions, so yes it's acceptable to post errors if the solution isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is [over clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql). Also in future development try to make you columns 1 word for example . `[Inbound Call Client Account]` would turn into `Inbound_Call_Client_Account`. This would make it easier to reference columns. The bottom query will get you all rows that are triplicate only, from there you can do any `CRUD` operation you like.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT [Inbound Call Client Account] as [account]
,convert(date,format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Inbound Call Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) as [Date]
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Activation Id] ORDER BY [Inbound Call Time] DESC) AS "Row_Number"
  FROM [Call_Table]
      where 
      convert(date,format(Dateadd(hh,1,[Inbound Call Time]),'dd/MM/yyyy'),103) >= '2017-09-01'
      and [Chargeable Duration] = 0
      and ([Inbound Connected Call Duration] IS NULL or [Inbound Connected Call Duration] <1)
      and [Inbound Call Type] = 'normal operator call') AS foo
WHERE foo.row_number = 3
```

Comment: I think this is the way forward but the problem is that the where conditions in the original query eliminate the duplicate rows that are pointers to the false positives. Of the inbound call types there is only 1 'normal operator call' in the triplicated call. It's a bit tough to explain but I need to use the knowledge gleaned from the non grouped query inside the grouped query. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure, without a better understanding of the data the best I can do is strip out the where clause and let you play with it.